# Can't get number of children from a snapshot

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I can't get the number of children returned by snapshot. I always get `Snap ((null)) (null)` when I write `print(self.newCars)` in another position:

```
class NewCarsViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    var firebase: FIRDatabaseReference?

    var newCars = FIRDataSnapshot()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.firebase = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL:"https://firebaseURL/").child("featuredCars")
        firebase?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            self.newCars = snapshot
            print("halim")
            print(self.newCars)
            //  print(snapshot.childrenCount) // I got the expected number of items
            for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
               //   print(rest.value ?? "")
            }
        })

    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NewCarCell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        return cell
            }

}
```

Comment: it work right now , I made a static class and I charged it in the AppDelegate

Comment: self.firebase = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL:"firebaseURL").child("featuredCars")
        firebase?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
           GetFeaturedCars.newCars = snapshot

Answer (score 0):

That code is working for me.

I would guess you are moving the print(self.newCars) outside of the Firebase block (closure).

It takes time for Firebase to return the data, and that data only becomes valid inside the closure.

If the print statement is outside of the closure, it's running before the data is returned from Firebase and it would be null.